# bmake error on Mandrive: "bmake: no system rules (sys.mk)"

Tags: freebsd, compiling, make, mandriva, bmake

I'm trying to use bmake to build OS161 on Mandriva. When I try to run bmake, I get the following error:

```
bmake: no system rules (sys.mk)
```

I get the same error, even when I run

```
bmake -m /usr/local/share/mk/sys.mk
```

I've checked, and the path I listed above exists, but regardless of what path I give it, even if I give it a garbage path, I get the same error.

This happens no matter what directory I run bmake in, so it's definitely not an OS161 problem. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

The -m option takes a directory name, not a filename.

`bmake -m /usr/local/share/mk`

Otherwise, your version of bmake doesn't match the version of the mk files in /usr/local/share/mk.